# Using PowerShell to Download Google Sheet Data to Local CSV - Credential Issues

Tags: powershell, csv, google-sheets, download

For a few months now, I've been utilizing a `PowerShell` script that automatically downloads my `Google Sheet` as a `CSV`. Something changed about a week ago - the file returned by the script is now html, which directs me to my `Gmail` login. I'm not sure if my credentials were previously cached or something, but I haven't been able to resolve this. If I click the URL manually, it successfully downloads as a CSV (as expected). But I have been unsuccessful in updating my `PowerShell` script (or anything else) to automate the process once again.

My `PowerShell` script:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
$client.DownloadFile("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/export?format=csv"
    ,"C:\Users\<local_location>\" +$enddate+ "_File.csv")
```

Comment: No idea how it worked in the first place tbh. But one method could be to use Selenium (can be used with PowerShell) to automate the whole thing including login to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the link manually, likely you browser will have some cookies from Google with a refresh token. Try opening the export link in an incognito browser window and you will likely see the same HTML as received by Powershell. If the Spreadsheet is shared with anyone with the link, then the Powershell script should work. If it isn't then the PowerShell script will need to be authorized before.